# tkinter picture error: bad screen distance

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, anaconda3

I'm trying to write a tkinter program, and I came across an error that I've never seen before while working with tkinter. I've searched around everywhere, and tried everything I can think of. This is my code so far:

```
x=tk.Canvas(top,width=1000,height=750,bg="grey")
x.pack()
y=tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\images (3)_CnyokaDvJmG1xu.png")
x.create_image(top,0,0,image=y)`
```

and this is error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 
1705, in __call__
   return self.func(*args)
 File "C:/Users/Admin/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 16, in open
   x.create_image(top,0,0,image=y).pack()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 
2489, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 
2480, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "."
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to supply containing widget when placing an image in a canvas, coordinates are enough:

```
x.create_image(0,0,image=y)
```

The error is because canvas does not accept a widget as coordinates.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 16, in open
    x.create_image(0,0,image=y)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2489, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2480, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage6" doesn't exist``

Comment: Can you please post a complete runnable code which produces the error.